# How can i populate 3 columns with a single array of strings by the order of column

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, styled-components

I have an array of strings like this:

```
const checkboxItems = [
    'a', 'b', 'c',
    'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i',
]
```

and I want to populate three columns by the column order, so the output will be:

```
a d g
b e h
c f i
```

I have a wrapper component with css like this:

```
const CheckboxWrapper = styled('div')`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
`;
```

and I need to render checkbox components in three columns with labels from `checkboxItems`. My component looks like this:

```
<CheckboxWrapper>
        {
            checkboxItems.map(item => {
                return <Checkbox
                    key={'checkBox'}
                    checked={false}
                    onClick={() => { }}
                >
                    <Label>{item}</Label>
                </Checkbox>
            })
        }
    </CheckboxWrapper>
```

Note that my current code renders items on this way:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

What am I doing wrong? An example will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you `.map()` over `checkboxItems` they're getting rendered in the order of appearance, whereas you need to render them transposed.

To get desired result, general approach would be to break your source array into chunks of length 3 (the number of columns), transposed according to desired order:

```
itemsToRender = Array(Math.ceil(checkboxItems.length/3))
          .fill()
          .map((_, i, s) => 
            Array(3)
              .fill()
              .map((_,j) => 
                checkboxItems[i+j*s.length]))
```

Following is a live demo of that approach:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const App = () => {
  const checkboxItems = ['First name','Last name','Email','Phone','Address','Gender','City','Postcode','Country/State','Country','Lifetime value','Tickets in period','Revenue in period','Permission to contact','Customer ID','Account ID','AS Customer tags','Product/Event','Price Category','Section','Row','Seat'],
        
        itemsToRender = Array(Math.ceil(checkboxItems.length/3))
          .fill()
          .map((_, i, s) => 
            Array(3)
              .fill()
              .map((_,j) => 
                checkboxItems[i+j*s.length]))
          
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {
        itemsToRender.map((row, rowIdx) => (
          <div key={rowIdx} className="row">
            {
              row.map((item, itemPos) => item && (
                <label key={itemPos} className="cell">
                  <input type="checkbox" value={item} />
                  {item}
                </label>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )          
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Another approach (to proceed with `grid` layout and rearrange items, using CSS and `repeat()` function in particular) is to make use of Material-UI styling (which is the case here) and set `grid-template-rows` dynamically, based on the number of rows it will take to wrap your list:

```js
const  { render } = ReactDOM,
       { FormControlLabel, Checkbox } = MaterialUI,
       { makeStyles } = MaterialUI

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const useStyles = rowNum => makeStyles({
  wrapper: {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${rowNum}, 1fr)`,
    gridAutoFlow: 'column'
  }
})

const App = () => {
  const checkboxItems = ['First name','Last name','Email','Phone','Address','Gender','City','Postcode','Country/State','Country','Lifetime value','Tickets in period','Revenue in period','Permission to contact','Customer ID','Account ID','AS Customer tags','Product/Event','Price Category','Section','Row','Seat'],
        classes = useStyles(Math.ceil(checkboxItems.length/3))()
        
  return(
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      {
        checkboxItems.map((item, itemIdx) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={itemIdx}
            control={
              <Checkbox
                name={item}
              />
            }
            label={item}
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is great, but when I apply this to my code using checkboxes, only one column is populated with checkboxes. Can you create example using checkboxes, please?

Comment: here you can take a look at my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-surf-tp4cy?file=/src/App.js:180-193

Comment: and I'm trying to achieve something like this https://imgur.com/cmeBW8r

Comment: @Milos : you may check out working demo [over here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vr6qdb)

Comment: @Milos : thanks for changing your mind, hopefully, what I share next won't make you to switch back :) I liked the idea of using (almost) pure CSS for arranging array items, so I have [elaborated the concept](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q9knmy) and I really enjoyed what it looked like (though, certain advanced stuff may seem a bit hard to comprehend)

Comment: I won't change my mind. You took a lot of effort to help me with my problem! Thanks a lot! I will try with your CSS solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Set [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) to `column` and `grid-template-rows` to 3 x 1fr:

```
const CheckboxWrapper = styled('div')`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
`;
```

Comment: this will create only one column

Comment: @Milos set `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr` ?

Comment: @Milos : while I like the concept (I have upvoted myself), the solution is incomplete, because when applied *as-is* it is not truly dynamic: to preserve fixed number of columns it requires `grid-template-rows` to be set dynamically (`repeat(n, 1fr)`) where  `n = Math.ceil(checkboxItems/3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
const checkboxItems = [
    'a', 'b', 'c',
    'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i',
]
const sortedCheckBox = []
const col = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < col; i++) {
  for (let j = i; j < checkboxItems.length; j += col) {
    sortedCheckBox.push(checkboxItems[j])
  }
}

console.log(sortedCheckBox)
```